# WP_Query pass a unique identifier to be used for action hook later?

Tags: wordpress

I can't find it in the WP codex, but is there a way to pass a unique identifier for a custom WP_Query?

I want to identify a particular query so I can perform an action hook function on it.

```
$args = array(
    'my_custom_id' => 'customidentifier'   <-- something like this??
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
 
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, It will be added to the `query_vars` property array, You can check for it later in actions for example

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $wp_query_obj ) {
        if ( ! empty( $wp_query_obj->query_vars['my_custom_id'] ) ) {
            // ...
        }
    },
    100,
    1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$args = array(
    'my_custom_id' => 'customidentifier',
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then to hook the action add this

```
function checkQueryForMy_custom_id( $my_query ){
  if( $my_query->get( 'my_custom_id' ) === 'customidentifier' ){
     //continue
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'checkQueryForMy_custom_id', 10 );
```

I didn't test this but should work.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't quite what I was asking. I need to be able to use pre_get_posts hook, and conditionally alter only that type of query.

Comment: @SeanRasmussen I've edited my response according to your needs.